# CocoaPods unable to update ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK pod

Tags: ios, cocoapods, skmaps

The current (installed) version of ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK is 2.4 and I'm trying to updated to the latest version 2.5.

However it is not updating neither failing.

I've run the command:

```
pod update
```

The output was:

```
Downloading dependencies
Using AFDownloadRequestOperation (2.0.1)
Installing AFNetworking 2.5.4 (was 2.5.3)
Using HMSegmentedControl (1.5.1)
Using MBProgressHUD (0.9.1)
Using Reachability (3.2)
Using SWRevealViewController (2.3.0)
Using ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK (2.4.0)
Using ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools (2.4.0)
Using ZipArchive (1.4.0)
Generating Pods project
Integrating client project
```

If I run the command:

```
pod outdated
```

The output is (Even after executing `pod update`):

```
Updating spec repositories
Analyzing dependencies
The following pod updates are available:
- ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK 2.4.0 -> 2.4.0 (latest version 2.5)
```

The contents of my Podfile is the following:

```
platform :ios, '7.1'

inhibit_all_warnings!

target 'MyTarget' do

pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK'
pod 'ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools'
pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'
pod 'MBProgressHUD', '~> 0.9'
pod 'SWRevealViewController', '~> 2.3'
pod 'HMSegmentedControl'

end
```

What could be causing this issue? Does anyone know how to fix it?

PS: I already tried a "clean" install, the output of `pod outdated` still the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK` is a dependency of `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools` and `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools` hasn't been updated to 2.5.

The [spec for ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTOOLS 2.4](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools/2.4.0/ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools.podspec.json) has the below dependency, meaning any 2.4 version of `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK` can be used, but not 2.5.

```
"dependencies": {
    "ScoutMaps-iOS-SDK": [
      "~> 2.4.0"
    ],
    ...
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to force it?

Comment: I'm not for sure if there is a way without a new pod spec being created. Even if there was a way to force 2.5 to be used, there still could be API incompatibilities between 2.4 and 2.5, breaking `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools`. The safest bet will be to wait for the developers to update `ScoutMaps-iOS-SDKTools` to 2.5.